# Why does my gem take so long to load?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm developing my first gem called [t_time_tracker](https://github.com/christiangenco/t_time_tracker) (woohoo!). All was going great in development; I optomized it as much as I possibly could to cut execution time down to as little as possible:

```sh
t_time_tracker[master*]% time ruby -Ilib ./bin/t_time_tracker 
You're not working on anything
0.07s user 0.03s system 67% cpu 0.141 total
```

(this is the "hello world" of my app - calling it with no parameters just prints out "You're not working on anything")

About a tenth of a second and uses 67% of my CPU - cool, I can live with that. It feels fairly instantaneous. Let's build it:

```sh
$ gem build t_time_tracker.gemspec
$ gem install ./t_time_tracker-0.0.0.gem
```

And do the exact same thing with the installed binary:

```sh
$ time t_time_tracker
You're not working on anything
t_time_tracker  0.42s user 0.06s system 93% cpu 0.513 total
```

Half a second?! Where did that come from?! Let's add some debugging output and include the system gem from the development binary to see where the bottleneck is:

```sh
t_time_tracker[master*]% time ruby ./bin/t_time_tracker  
(starting binary)
(require 'time' and 'optparse')
0.041432
(before `require 't_time_tracker')
0.497135
(after `require 't_time_tracker')
(Gem.loaded_specs.keys = t_time_tracker)
(initializing TTimeTracker class)
You're not working on anything
ruby ./bin/t_time_tracker  0.44s user 0.07s system 91% cpu 0.551 total
```

Alright, so the `require 't_time_tracker' line seems to be the culprit. Let's try again in irb to narrow it down further:

```sh
$ irb
>> t=Time.now; require 't_time_tracker'; puts Time.now-t
0.046792
=> nil
```

...what? But that was just taking half a second! Let's try building the gem with our debugging output:

```sh
$ gem build t_time_tracker.gemspec
$ gem install ./t_time_tracker-0.0.0.gem
$ time t_time_tracker
(starting binary) <---noticeable half second delay before this line shows up
(require 'time' and 'optparse')
0.050458
(before `require 't_time_tracker')
0.073789
(after `require 't_time_tracker')
(Gem.loaded_specs.keys = t_time_tracker)
(initializing TTimeTracker class)
You're not working on anything
t_time_tracker  0.42s user 0.06s system 88% cpu 0.546 total
```

So yeah, where is this 0.5 second delay coming from? I usually wouldn't care, but this is something that I'm calling about fifty times a day to update what I'm doing. 50 * 0.5 seconds * 365 days * 70 years = 15 days of lost life.

System information:

Mac OS X 10.7.3. 2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo. 4 GB ram. ruby 1.9.2p290.

```sh
% gem -v
1.8.10<---noticeable half second delay before this line shows up
% gem list | wc -l
209
```

Comment: What is the performance like on 1.9.3?

Comment: Interesting... `rvm 1.9.3 && gem install t_time_tracker` gives me my super fast execution time again (0.100 seconds total), but I'm suspicious that this is just because `gem list | wc -l` = 7. Hmmm...

Comment: After `gem install rails`, `gem list | wc -l` = 33, and `time t` is an average of about 0.21. Is the solution just "don't install a lot of gems"?

Comment: Having lots of gems installed shouldn't affect much; I have 139 installed at the moment.

Comment: I thought it was an ongoing thing that having lots of gems does affect gem loading time. 1.9.3 improved this somewhow

Comment: Do you have more granular data, like with running in a profiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been a while since I looked at this but RubyGems has, in the past (and maybe the present), taken a long time to load for mainly two reasons:

- It would load many relatively expensive libraries like 'time' via 'yaml'.  Usually you don't care because it's slow relative to ruby all by itself, not slow compared to the run time of many scripts.
- It would scan over all the installed gems and load the most recent gemspecs into memory.  This took a long time if you have a lot of gems.

These issues may or may not still be in play.  However you'll *always* have some overhead from RubyGems.  If you really need performance, then just set up your load path yourself!  Ruby without RubyGems is very fast, as you know.

To see where your gem is installed:

```
gem list -d YOUR_GEM_NAME
```

You'll see the install directory.  Your gem will be at INSTALL_DIR/gems/GEM_NAME-VERSION so try executing:

```
time ruby -IINSTALL_DIR/gems/GEM_NAME-VERSION/lib INSTALL_DIR/gems/GEM_NAME-VERSION/bin/t_time_tracker
```

That's a lot, but you should be able to wrap this in a separate script, something like this (name it t_time_tracker):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -IINSTALL_DIR/gems/GEM_NAME-VERSION/lib
load 'INSTALL_DIR/gems/GEM_NAME-VERSION/bin/t_time_tracker'
```

Then:

```
chmod +x t_time_tracker
time ./t_time_tracker
```

And put that file anywhere along your PATH. RubyGems does for you automatically, but of course you then accept the overhead of RubyGems.

Comment: great but what about for a gem that is being distributed to other users?

Answer (score 0):

The `$LOAD_PATH` being used within your gem is likely to be the culprit. Ideally the path for your `lib` folder is first on that array.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably because you have it "from local" gem. So ruby will have to check other paths before he wil pick him up.

eg. if you will have file called json.rb and gem installed globally called json when doing

```
require 'json'
```

he will find first gem and load it :). Local path is last to be loaded. If you will bundle the gem and install you will see massive speed improvement just because of different location in gems. I wouldn't worry much about this lack of load time in development.